# Inequality between product measure and its projection

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, inequality

$\newcommand{\smin}{\setminus}
\newcommand{\sset}{\subseteq}$If $\mu$ is a measure on $X$, $ \nu $ a measure on $Y, \gamma $ a measure on $X \times Y$ s.t. $ \gamma(A \times Y) = \mu (A) $ and $\gamma(X \times B) = \nu(B)$, $ \forall A \sset X $ $\mu$-measurable and $B \sset Y$ $\nu$-measurable then 
\begin{array}\\
 &\gamma ( X \times Y \smin A \times B) \\
& \leq \gamma(((X \smin A) \times Y) \cup (X \times (Y \smin B))) \\
&\leq \gamma((X \smin A) \times Y) + \gamma((X \times Y) \smin B)\\
&=  \mu(X \smin A) + \nu (Y \smin B)
\end{array}

Does this make sense?

Comment: Just so you know, $X\times Y\setminus A\times B\neq (X\setminus A)\times (Y\setminus B)$ in general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it make sense and actually it's even simpler: note that
$$
  X\times Y\setminus A\times B \subseteq [(X\setminus A)\times Y]\cup[X\times (Y\setminus B)]
$$
which if not obvious, may follow with the help of these pictures:
$$
  X\times Y\setminus A\times B
$$
[image]
$$
  (X\setminus A)\times Y
$$
[image]
$$
  X\times (Y\setminus B)
$$
[image]

As a result you get
$$
  \gamma(X\times Y\setminus A\times B)\leq \mu(X\setminus A) + \nu(Y\setminus B)
$$